# Calling function which is in a function in an array

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call function with button.
But this function is located in another function, which is in an array.

```
demo = {
    volej: function(param) {
      (new initChartist).users(param);
    },
    initPickColor: function(){
        $('.pick-class-label').click(function(){
            var new_class = $(this).attr('new-class');  
            var old_class = $('#display-buttons').attr('data-class');
            var display_div = $('#display-buttons');
            if(display_div.length) {
            var display_buttons = display_div.find('.btn');
            display_buttons.removeClass(old_class);
            display_buttons.addClass(new_class);
            display_div.attr('data-class', new_class);
            }
        });
    },

    initChartist: function(){ 
    function users(cas) {
          $.post("getUsersReg.php", {datum: cas}, function(datas) {
            var casy;
            if(cas == "Rok") {
              casy = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
            } else if(cas == "Mesic") {
              casy = ['1. Týždeň', '2. Týždeň', '3. Týždeň', '4. Týždeň', 'Zbytek měsíce'];
            } else if(cas == "Den") {
              casy = ['Pon', 'Út', 'St', 'Čt', 'Pá', 'So', 'Ne'];
            }
    }
        var data = {
          labels: label,
          series: [uzivatelu]
        };
        /*data = {
            labels: [mesice[3], mesice[5]],
            series: [
              [1, 2]
            ]
          };*/

        var options = {
            seriesBarDistance: 10,
            axisX: {
                showGrid: true
            },
            height: "245px"
        };

        var responsiveOptions = [
          ['screen and (max-width: 640px)', {
            seriesBarDistance: 5,
            axisX: {
              labelInterpolationFnc: function (value) {
                return value[0];
              }
            }
          }]
        ];

        Chartist.Bar('#chartActivity', data, options, responsiveOptions);
      });
    }
}
}
```

I'm calling it with this code:

```
<button  onClick="demo.initChartist().users('Now');">Date</button>
```

How can I start that function from onClick?

Thank you in advance for your replies!

Comment: Why is the code inside `users` in the first place and not just directly in `initChartist`?

Comment: Because i'll have more functions in that one, which defines charts.
This function is only for one chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call function as you want, you have to change your code, like so

```
initChartist: function(){ 
  function users(cas) {
    $.post("getUsersReg.php", {datum: cas}, function(datas) {
      var casy;
      if (cas == "Rok") {
        casy = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
      } else if(cas == "Mesic") {
        casy = ['1. Týždeň', '2. Týždeň', '3. Týždeň', '4. Týždeň', 'Zbytek měsíce'];
      } else if(cas == "Den") {
        casy = ['Pon', 'Út', 'St', 'Čt', 'Pá', 'So', 'Ne'];
      }
    }    
  }

  return { users: users };
}
```

However, maybe would be better to move `users` to `demo` scope?